# R - Check if a subset of columns in a dataframe are all NA

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe that looks a bit like the following. I would like to edit the match column so that if all of the columns that start with "Flag" are *NA*, then I would like to print NA in the match column. Otherwise, I would like the original values to remain.

```
#Toy dataframe
 ID Flag_A Flag_B Flag_C Flag_D Flag_E match
<NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA>  0
  M      Z     A     <NA>   I      A   1
  F      M    <NA>    R     Q      B   1
  T    <NA>   <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA>  0
  P      N     V      L     J      D   0
  L      O     U     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  1

#Desired Output
 ID Flag_A Flag_B Flag_C Flag_D Flag_E match
<NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA>  NA
  M      Z     A     <NA>   I      A   1
  F      M    <NA>    R     Q      B   1
  T    <NA>   <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA>  NA
  P      N     V      L     J      D   0
  L      O     U     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way:

```
# identify the columns that start with "Flag"
flag_cols = startsWith(names(df), "Flag")
# see which rows have the same number of NAs as the number of flag cols
all_na = rowSums(is.na(df[flag_cols])) == sum(flag_cols)
# update match column accordingly
df[all_na, "match"] = NA
```